# what is the complexity of recursive summation

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, recursion, recursive-algorithms, dynamic-programming

Can someone tell me the exact complexity of this recursion ? this is actually formula for below question ( solved in recursive brute force way )

> There is n steps stairs and a person standing at the bottom want to reach at top. Person can take max k steps at a time ( i.e. he can take 1, 2 , 3,.. upto k steps).Count how many ways person can climb the stairs.

f(n,k) =
\begin{cases}
\sum_{i=1}^k f(n-i,k) \,  & \text{if $k$ > 1} \\\\
1, & \text{if $k$ = 1}
\end{cases}

Comment: This is the number of compositions of n into parts with maximum size k. A table is in https://oeis.org/A048003 , which has formulas and cross-references to special cases.

Answer (score 0):

Since this problem is tagged `dynamic-programming`, here are my two cents on how this can be solved in $O(n)$ memory and $O(n)$ time using dynamic-programming.

The key-idea is maintaining a prefix-sum sequence (as an array in memory). It is a sequence that satisfies the property `pre[i] = f[0] + f[1] + ... + f[i]`. Consider the base-states: `pre[i] := 0` for `i < 0` and `pre[0] = f[0] = 1`. Now we recurse:

```
for i in range[1, n]:
  f[i] = pre[i - 1] - pre[(i - k) - 1]
  pre[i] = pre[i - 1] + f[i]
```

If you're not familiar with prefix-sums, note that I employed the fact that `f[i] + f[i + 1] + ... + f[j]` is the same as `pre[j] - pre[i - 1]`.

Comment: Hey thanks, I know the DP solution of it. I am looking for complexity of recursive solution , am not able to mathematically derive it. BTW DP solution has complexity of O(nk), you are missing inner look of k ( 1,2,3,...k).

Comment: @abhi No, I did not miss anything. My answer is correct and it runs in O(n) (you would know if you even bothered to read it).

Comment: Sorry i missed.Your solution using prefix sum looks pretty good.thanks